# staircase behavior with pivoted data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, pivot, pivot-table

Hail to the fellow programmers and query writers,

I have this beautiful query

```
SELECT ID, [1] AS coL1, [15] AS coL2, [2] AS coL3, [16] AS coL4, [12] AS coL5
FROM MY_TABLE
PIVOT (sum(INT_VALUE) FOR FUND_CODE IN ([1],[2],[15],[16],[12])) AS p
--GROUP BY ID, [1] , [15]  , [2] , [16] , [12] 
ORDER BY ID ASC
```

That returns me data like this:

```
10001      182       NULL      NULL      NULL
10001      NULL      81        NULL      NULL
10001      NULL      NULL      182       NULL
10001      NULL      NULL      NULL      81
10002      165       NULL      NULL      NULL
10002      NULL      73        NULL      NULL
10002      NULL      NULL      165       NULL
10002      NULL      NULL      NULL      73
```

The 10001 and 10002 are two primary keys, and I'd like to show my data like this:

```
10001      182       81      182      81
10002      165       73      165      73
```

I tried this commented GROUP BY to no avail.
Any hints? Does it involve COALESCE?

Comment: I believe this website has the answer but I couldn't see the light yet.  "http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2007/07/03/the-pivot-operator.aspx".

Comment: What logic are you using to determine that col1's value 182 gets col2's value of 81 rather than 73?

Comment: in your example as it stands currently, 10001 **isn't** *the* primary key - there are two rows for it. Possibly the primary key should be ID, plus some other column?

Comment: yes, this is a simplified sample. The ID plus other one is the PK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in CASE...

```
SELECT ID,
SUM(CASE WHEN FUND_CODE = 1 THEN VR_MOVIMENTACAO_QUOTA ELSE 0 END) coL1,
SUM(CASE WHEN FUND_CODE = 15 THEN VR_MOVIMENTACAO_QUOTA ELSE 0 END) coL2,
SUM(CASE WHEN FUND_CODE = 2 THEN VR_MOVIMENTACAO_QUOTA ELSE 0 END) coL3,
SUM(CASE WHEN FUND_CODE = 16 THEN VR_MOVIMENTACAO_QUOTA ELSE 0 END) coL4,
SUM(CASE WHEN FUND_CODE = 12 THEN VR_MOVIMENTACAO_QUOTA ELSE 0 END) coL5

FROM MY_TABLE
GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score 2):

SELECT ID
     ,SUM(1)  AS 'col1'
         ,SUM(15) AS 'col2'
     ,SUM(2)  AS 'col3'
     ,SUM(16) AS 'col4'
         ,SUM(12) AS 'col5'
FROM Table GROUP BY ID

Comment: thanks, DOC, but I abandoned the PIVOT in favor of CASE and did just like you see below: